# Flask API not working, also unable to read csv by request.files.get

Tags: python, api, csv, flask

I new to creating rest apis for model deployment. I am trying to write a code to host an api from my system. I have read all relevant questions and tried different ways but none of them answer the problem I'm facing.

I have written the below code. But the API is not working.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
swagger = Swagger(app)

#def main():
@app.route('/',methods=['GET','POST'])
def predict_inv():
    """Example file endpoint
    ---
    parameters:
      - name: input_file
        in: formData
        type: file
        required: true
    """
    print("entry in to the job")
    #dfinput = pd.read_csv(request.files.get("input_file"),encoding='cp1252')
    #dfinput = pd.read_csv(request.files.get('uploaded_file'),encoding="utf8")
    dfinput = pd.read_csv(request.files.get('file'))
    print("entry")
    PicklePath = "C:/Users/koyeli/data/gbsemail_adaV0.1.pkl"
    model1 = joblib.load(PicklePath)
    print("model loaded")
    #FilePath1 = "C:/Users/z001133/Desktop/work files/customer quality/SAFETY/data/jan1st.csv"
    dfclean = clean_data(dfinput['Body'])
    filenm1 = "email_classification_ml_result"
    predict(model1,filenm1,dfclean)
    print("before return")
    return 'OK'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

Im getting the following error.

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2019 09:43:44] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\z026355\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\z026355\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\z026355\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\z026355\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\z026355\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\z026355\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\z026355\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\z026355\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\z026355\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\z026355\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "<ipython-input-77-0c3a1ef05475>", line 18, in predict_invoice

  File "C:\Users\z026355\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 678, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\z026355\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 424, in _read
    filepath_or_buffer, encoding, compression)
  File "C:\Users\z026355\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 218, in get_filepath_or_buffer
    raise ValueError(msg.format(_type=type(filepath_or_buffer)))
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'NoneType'>
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2019 09:43:44] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2019 09:43:44] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2019 09:43:44] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=debugger.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2019 09:43:45] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2019 09:43:45] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=ubuntu.ttf HTTP/1.1" 200 -
entry in to the job
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2019 09:43:45] "GET /?__debugger__=yes&cmd=resource&f=console.png HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

It is printing "Entry to job" but api is not working.
Below is the error im getting in api.

```
builtins.ValueError
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'NoneType'>
```

Is there a problem for reading the csv file or is there something wrong with my approach in code. Please suggest.

Comment: request.files.get('file') is giving you none, thats why it is unable to open up the file. please print the request.files.get('file') alone to see if you are gettign the value. once you get the correct value here, you'll be able to read the file

Comment: The api is not working, it is showing error so its not proceeding to make an input.

Comment: I would use pandas for this and import it at the beginning of your code. Pandas makes it easy to read CSV files and then save the result to a DataFrame and transform that data to be used programmatically. Then can apply that data to an api. The best part is u can test all this in a jupyter notebook to prove it works how u want it before saving it a python file. I would also plan test for each line of code to prove your data flow. Even something like print(“test(n): ”, obj) works great per block of code.

Comment: I have imported pandas as pd at the beginning of the code. i have problem only with creating an api for the model. It is facing some problem with dfinput = pd.read_csv(request.files.get('file'))

Answer (score 0):

You need csv reader for reading csv file 
try like this

```
from flask import Flask, make_response, request
import io
import csv

app = Flask(__name__)

def transform(text_file_contents):
    return text_file_contents.replace("=", ",")


@app.route('/')
def form():
    return """
        <html>
            <body>
                <h1>Transform a file demo</h1>

                <form action="/transform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" name="data_file" />
                    <input type="submit" />
                </form>
            </body>
        </html>
    """

@app.route('/transform', methods=["POST"])
def transform_view():
    f = request.files['data_file']
    if not f:
        return "No file"

    stream = io.StringIO(f.stream.read().decode("UTF8"), newline=None)
    csv_input = csv.reader(stream)
    #print("file contents: ", file_contents)
    #print(type(file_contents))
    print(csv_input)
    for row in csv_input:
        print(row)
    return 'OK'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001, debug=True)
```

Now check

Comment: with edited code, the form is getting created. I am able to upload the file but after submit in/transform route error is coming: builtins.UnicodeDecodeError